# Labels are cropped in drill-down pie chart (amCharts)

Tags: amcharts

We have implemented pie chart using amCharts. But when drill down occurs, the pulled slices label are cropped. How can we fix this issue?

```
chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chart_1", {
  "type": "pie",
  "autoMargins": false,
  "marginRight": 10,
  "marginBottom": 10,
  "dataProvider": generateChartData(),
  "titleField": "SubTypeName",
  "valueField": "Weight",
  "outlineColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "colorField": "Color",
  "balloonText": "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>",
  "pulledField": "pulled",
  "addClassNames": true,

  "labelRadius": 3,
  "radius": "40%",
  "innerRadius": "30%",

  "angle": 25,
  "depth3D": 13,

  "legend": {
    "autoMargins": false,
    "marginTop": 10,
    "marginBottom": 10,
  }

} );
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code to your chart?

Comment: Please note, I have removed a trailing comma in your code. Trailing commas while OK in modern browsers would result in JS error in older IEs.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can do work around this issue. You can apply one or combination of the below:

1) Lower [`radius`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#radius) property. This will leave more room for slice labels when pulled out. Or remove this parameter altogether. The chart will then auto-calculate the pie radius so that labels are always visible even if pulled out.

2) Set [`pullOutRadius`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#pullOutRadius) to some lower percent value than default 20%. This will make slices pull out less.

3) Limit width of the labels by setting [`maxLabelWidth`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#maxLabelWidth) (default 200 pixels). This will make the labels break into multiple lines, effectively reducing it's width and chance being cut off.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [AmCharts Tutorial](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/fitting-pie-charts-small-containers/) "Fitting pie charts into small containers"

1. Make the chart container bigger.
2. Wrap it around some other div to confine the chart to the same space.

#

```
#chartwrapper{
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
#chartdiv  {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  width : 260px;
  height : 260px;
}
```

[image: Pie containers]